# Augmented form of three equation with one extra unknown

Tags: linear-algebra

I am being asked to find all solutions to the system of linear equations:
$$
2u+v−w+z = 1\\
v−2w = 2\\
w+z = −1
$$

The problem is that there is an extra term $2u$. Ignoring $2u$ the augmented matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&1&:&1\\1&-2&0&:&2\\0&1&1&:&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Is it still possible to use augmented matrix and echelon form to solve this system?

Comment: You can still use an augmented matrix form, but you shouldn't ignore the $2u$. It basically gives you an extra degree of freedom.

Comment: Not a good idea in general. In this case, the equations happen to force $u=0$. In the same example with different numbers, one could bring the $u$ stuff to the other side and trat it as a parameter.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt So I need to have a 5x4 augmented matrix instead of 4x3?

Comment: You will want a 3x5 matrix instead of a 3x4 matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use an augmented matrix and reduced row echelon form to solve any system of linear equations. In this case, the matrix which you will want to reduce is 
$$\left[ \begin{matrix} 
2&1&-1&1&:&1\\ 
0&1&-2&0&:&2\\
0&0&1&1&:&-1\\ 
\end{matrix} \right]$$

This is because you are trying to solve the equation:
$$\left[ \begin{matrix} 
2&1&-1&1\\ 
0&1&-2&0\\
0&0&1&1\\ 
\end{matrix} \right]\left[ \begin{matrix} 
u\\
v\\
w\\
z
\end{matrix} \right]=\left[ \begin{matrix} 
1\\
2\\
-1
\end{matrix} \right]$$